# Memcopy Instruction in Risc V

Tags: risc-v

I designed a Risc V 32-bit single cycle processor without pipelining for a project. We are given to implement a new instruction called "Memcopy". It copies an array of size N from one location to another location (N>1). But is it possible to implement this kind of instruction in a single cycle processor, because copying N value from memory to another location it has to execute load and store instructions N times? So in a multicycle processor it is possible. But what about implementing it on a single cycle processor?

Comment: I think you’ve identified the problem, being that the operation necessarily takes multiple cycles.  I suppose the nearest you would get would be an instruction that reads from an address held in one register, writes to an address held in another register and decrements a counter in a third register, not incrementing the PC until the counter is zero.  But to achieve that in single-cycle I’d imagine you’d need at least two memory buses

Comment: @Frog Put that as an answer without the *I think*, and *I think* that we can wrap this up.

Comment: @Frog: `you’d need at least two memory buses` or a write buffer. When `N` is small enough, you just may get away with `N` cache access times for the reads, and a non-empty write buffer in `N` cycles.

Comment: Maybe there's a detail about your problem missing here: does the *effect* of the instruction be there after a single cycle, or is it just that the next cycle, the next instruction can be worked on, as long as it doesn't touch the source or destination of the memcpy instruction?

Comment: Someone is confused about the concept of "RISC". This proposed "memcopy" instruction is clearly a CISC concept. Shoehorning it into a RISC architecture is going to be ugly at best. On a RISC machine, you would write a software loop to do that kind of copying -- and then design the RISC instruction(s) to make that loop as efficient as possible.

Comment: @DaveTweed that looks like an answer to the assignment that the OP was given by the instructor

Answer (score 1):

You’ve identified the problem, being that the operation necessarily takes multiple cycles. I suppose the nearest you would get would be an instruction that reads from an address held in one register, writes to an address held in another register and decrements a counter in a third register, not incrementing the PC until the counter is zero. But to achieve that in single-cycle I’d imagine you’d need at least two memory buses or some kind of buffer/cache arrangement that doesn’t belong in a RISC processor.  As @Dave Tweed points out, the problem calls for multiple instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve that in a processor that otherwise executes all its instructions in single cycles is to microcode it. The instruction then turns into a small "program", possibly made out of other instructions held in a ROM. That program executes over a number of cycles to perform the memcopy.

You may need a "hidden" register for this, because you will need to keep intermediate values somewhere between "load" and "store". Either that or explicitly have the instruction specify a register to use for that purpose, as well as which register contains the count.

Important consideration: what if there is a hardware exception (page fault) half way through the memcopy? What about an interrupt?

For inspiration, see [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2022-06/Base-Instructions/CPYP--CPYM--CPYE--Memory-Copy-).